# Backup or copy Azure Mobile Service scripts?

Tags: version-control, backup, azure-mobile-services

I am running a mobile service with an increasing amount of scripted functionality. I want to have these scripts somehow stored in a smart format for version control. I'm having hard time finding any information on such scenarios. Is it even possible Azure -> VS2012 (and TFS) or VS2012 (and TFS) -> Azure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently that is not supported on the portal itself. You can do that by using the Command Line Interface, however, as was shown in this [blog post](http://www.thejoyofcode.com/Getting_started_with_the_CLI_and_backing_up_your_scripts_Day_4_.aspx). Basically, you can store the scripts in whichever source control system you want (the post uses Git, but it would work with TFS as well) and use the CLI to update your service whenever a new version of the script is checked in.

You can also vote up the [source control feature suggestion](https://mobileservices.uservoice.com/forums/182281-feature-requests/suggestions/3331880-source-control-for-api-in-portal) on the UserVoice for the system, to have that functionality implemented in the service itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can now link your Azure Mobile scripts to a git repo directly from the Azure Mobile Portal Dashboard, allowing you to edit scripts from VS2012 or another editor.